# Xcode generates seemingly invalid code from OpenCL kernel

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opencl

Xcode automatically generates code for submitting OpenCL kernels to dispatch queues but it seems that it generates invalid code which can't be compiled for one of my kernels. The problem is with a struct definition:

```
typedef struct {
    float4 position;    ///< The point position.
    float4 velocity;    ///< The point velocity.
    float intensity;    ///< The point intensity.
    int links[6];       ///< The point links specified as indexes for other points in the array.
    float align;        ///< Dummy for alignment.
} PointElement;
```

This code is generated by Xcode:

```
typedef struct  {
  cl_float4 position;
  cl_float4 velocity;
  cl_float intensity;
  int [6] links;
  cl_float align;
} _PointElement_unalign;
```

I'm not expert at obscure C syntax variants but it surely `int [6] links;` is not valid C and therefore does not compile.

Why does Xcode do this? Have I done something wrong myself or is this a bug?

Comment: May be this is something that Apples OpenCL compiler can understand ?

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this issue? I'm encountering the same

Comment: Nope, gave up and just didn't use this features.